# How to hack Win32 API to get character limit to 32K

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string, file

I want to use prefix `\\\?\` as stated in this msdn BCL Team Blog, [Long Paths in .NET, Part 2 of 3: Long Path Workarounds [Kim Hamilton]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/03/26/long-paths-in-net-part-2-of-3-long-path-workarounds-kim-hamilton.aspx)

Even after going through it again and again, I couldn't figure out how to actually use this feature, wondering if anyone can tell me simplest way to use it and how.

Note: I want to use it for creating a directory

Comment: The link you provided gives "step by step" instructions including relevant source code... BTW: you can't create a file or directory name longer than ca. 250 characters... the link describes a way to have a path which is max. 32 K long... thus your question is really unclear... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Win32 functions and P/Invoke to achieve this. Use the Unicode version of the API.

Here's what you're looking for:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CreateDirectory(string lpPathName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

public static void CreateDir(string dirPath)
{
    if (!CreateDirectory(@"\\?\" + dirPath, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        throw new IOException("Could not create dir");
    }
}
```

[`CreateDirectory` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[More information about how naming works in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thats what i exactly was looking for since yesterday, thanks lot, but there is one problem, it does creates folder of characters but at one point it doesn;t allows me to open the created folder. sounds like a file access problem, i think

Comment: How are you opening your folder? If you tried using Windows Explorer then it won't work because the limit is still MAX_PATH (260) for explorer.
You'll have to use only Win32 Unicode API to access your directory. For instance, the unicode definition of `CreateFile` can successfully return a handle to your directory.

Comment: is it just for folder name or is it for Directory path as well sir, as i want to download folders in a sharepoint site and its webs and sub webs and so on, and then pass them to clients, so i wonder how clients will be able to open the folders.

Comment: the folder having directory path longer then 260 characters

Comment: @TimeToThine - Sharepoine website is accessed through a browser.  The character path limit wouldn't be inposed.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Ramhound  I would recommend you and the person who said its a great comment to read a little about share point before posting a stupid comment like you just did !